# Proof of property of given homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Given that $f$ to be group homomorphism from $\mathbb R^*\to\mathbb R^*$ and I want proof of property "If $x>0$ then $f(x)>0$". Please give me hint or something so I can proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

If $x>0$, then 
$$x=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}$$ so $$f(x)=f(\sqrt{x}.\sqrt{x})=f(\sqrt{x})f(\sqrt{x})=\Big(f(\sqrt{x})\Big)^2 >0$$

> Additional exercise: Prove in general that every automorphism of $\Bbb{R}^*$ maps positive numbers to positive numbers and negative numbers to negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $a \in \Bbb R^*$, we have $f(a^2) = f(a)^2$

Comment: Ok this is homomorphism property but I didn't get how to use it.

Comment: Another hint: if $a \in \Bbb R^*$, which numbers can $a^2$ be?

Comment: If a in R* then $a^2$ will be greater than zero and since f(a^2)=(f(a))^2 this says f(a^2)>0. Correct?